# Function to convert Text URL into HTML URL

Tags: php, regex, url

My code is:

```
$rawhtml = file_get_contents( "site url" );

$pat= '/((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]/i';

preg_match_all($pat,$rawhtml,$matches1);

foreach($matches1[1] as $plinks)
{
    $links_array[]=$plinks;
}
```

After testing several situations I noted that the function had some "leaks". The link gets broken if there is whitespace.

For example I have this text URL in a variable:

```
$rawhtml = " http://www.filesonic.com/file/2185085531/TEST Voice 640-461 Test Cert Guide.epub
"
```

The result should be one link by line:

```
http://www.filesonic.com/file/2185085481/TEST Voice (640)+461 Test Cert Guide.pdf
```

but the result is

```
http://www.filesonic.com/file/2185085531/TEST
```

Sometimes extracted links also contains  `,` or `'` or `"`  at the end. How to get rid of these?

Comment: What you ask may well be impossible. How can the script know that in `"visit http://example.com now"` the space isn't part of the URL, but in `"download http://example.com/white space.pdf now"` it is?

Comment: Technically the spaces don't belong in the URL. Working around that lack of proper syntax would only be a hack. And without knowing the actual source page, hard to fix. But have you considered an alternative approach mentioned in the various other [extract links form html](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract%20links%20from%20html%20php) questions?

Comment: how to get rid of those commas,quotes or double quotes from the extracted links

Answer (score 0):

> how to get rid of those commas,quotes or double quotes from the extracted links

One could use `(?<![,'"])` to exclude something at the end. But your problem is that you simply shouldn't use the trailing character class:

```
 [^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]
```

That's what matches `"` and `'`.

As a hackish workaround to the other problem, the first character class could be augmented with a space.

```
 [\w#$&+,\/:;=?@. -]+
                 ▵
```

As said, that's probably not a good solution and might lead to other mismatches.